# Is it Possible to Update a Lucene Document using its Document ID?

Tags: lucene

A `ScoreDoc[]` array contains all the document ids from a search. I would like to use these document ids to update a single document. In this particular instance I cannot uniquely identify the row I wish to update, as the given terms will result in matching multiple documents.

Imagine a query where 1:a, 2:b and the following documents are returned

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6
doc 1: a b c d e f
doc 2: a b g h i j
doc 3: a b k l m n
```

I am basically making an update to fields 3 and 4, but want to leave 5 and 6 intact.

Currently I can grab these rows, make the updates I want, but I can't figure out a way to update them in the index.

An `indexWriter.updateDocuments(...)` or an `indexwriter.DeleteDocuments(...)` will result in document 1, 2 3 being deleted.

Since I have the documentId, I assume there is a way for me to update the index with it.

Answer (score 6):

Lucene doesn't allow the updating of fields in a document.   It is strictly a delete/add mechanism.

A document's docId can be change during optimization, merging, etc. so relying on that to always be the same isn't something you want to do.   You should put your own field into the document that won't change over time and use that instead.

Comment: To clarify, IndexWriter.UpdateDocument(Term, Document) just deletes _all_ documents having the term, then adds the provided document. Document identifiers are static and unchanged for a specific IndexReader instance (since merges aren't used until a reader is opened/reopened). You can keep track of your document identifiers as long as you also keep track of what reader instance it is associated with.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to delete by docid: [IndexWriter.tryDeleteDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#tryDeleteDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader,%20int%29).  Having deleted the document, you can then add the new one, which, as stated by others, is how Lucene executes an update.

The documentation linked above provides some interesting information on why it's called **try**DeleteDocument